# mpiexec was unable to launch the specified application as it could not find an executable (np)

Tags: c, mpi, cluster-analysis, cluster-computing, openmpi

can anyone help me out with this?
Everytime I do qsub file.pbs i get this error:
mpiexec was unable to launch the specified application as it could not find an executable:

Executable: –np

This is my main file.c

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int menum, nproc;
    int n, nloc, tag, i;
    int *x, *xloc;
    MPI_Status status;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &menum);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nproc);

    if(menum == 0) {
    //int nNum = atoi(argv[1]);
    x = (int*)malloc(10000 * sizeof(int));
    for(i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            x[i] = 1;
        }
    }
    MPI_Bcast(&n,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    
    nloc = n / nproc;
    int rest = n % nproc;
    if (menum < rest) {
        nloc = nloc + 1;
    }
    xloc = (int*)malloc(nloc * sizeof(int));


    if (menum == 0) {
        free(xloc);
        xloc = x;
        int start = 0;
        int tmp = nloc;
        for(i = 1; i < nproc; i++) {
            start = start + tmp;
            tag = 22 + i;

            //I primi rest-1 processori hanno un n in più
            if(i == rest) { tmp = tmp - 1; }
            MPI_Send(&x[start], tmp, MPI_INT, i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    } else {
        tag = 22 + menum;
        MPI_Recv(xloc, nloc, MPI_INT, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    }
    
    int sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < nloc; i++) {
        sum = sum + xloc[i];
    }
    
    int partialSum = 0;
    if (menum == 0) {
        for(i = 1; i < nproc; i++) {
            tag = 80 + i;
            MPI_Recv(&partialSum, 1, MPI_INT, i, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            sum = sum + partialSum;
        }
    } else {
        tag = 80 + menum;
        MPI_Send(&sum, 1, MPI_INT, 0, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    
    
    if (menum == 0) {
        printf("Processor %d totale %d\n", menum,sum);
    }

    free(xloc);
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the file.pbs:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -q studenti
#PBS -l nodes=8
#PBS -N SommaPrima
#PBS -o SommaPrima.out
#PBS -e SommaPrima.err

NCPU=`wc -l < $PBS_NODEFILE`
cat $PBS_NODEFILE
PBS_O_WORKDIR=$PBS_O_HOME/SommaStrat1

echo "Compiling"
/usr/lib64/openmpi/1.4-gcc/bin/mpicc -o $PBS_O_WORKDIR/SommaPrima $PBS_O_WORKDIR/SommaPrima.c

echo "Executing"
/usr/lib64/openmpi/1.4-gcc/bin/mpiexec -machinefile $PBS_NODEFILE –np $NCPU $PBS_O_WORKDIR/SommaPrima
```

Finally this is the file.err

```
/homes/DMA/PDC/2021/SommaStrat1/SommaPrima.c: In function ‘main’:
/homes/DMA/PDC/2021/SommaStrat1/SommaPrima.c:17: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’
/homes/DMA/PDC/2021/SommaStrat1/SommaPrima.c:29: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
mpiexec was unable to launch the specified application as it could not find an executable:

Executable: –np
Node: wn277.scope.it

while attempting to start process rank 0.
```

I also tried to change -np to just -n in the pbs file, but it will print out the same error and Executable: -n

Comment: add `set -x` in your script and add `SommaPrima.err` to the question.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Ok, I have now added SommaPrima.err and.. where do I have to set -x in my script?

Comment: right after the `#PBS` directives

Comment: It still prompts out the same error.
I did this way 
#PBS -q studenti
#PBS -l nodes=8
#PBS -N SommePrima
#PBS -o SommaPrima.out
#PBS -e SommaPrima.err
-set x

Comment: the goal here is to get some logs in order to diagnose the issue. please update `SommaPrima.err`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I added the file.err to the question. Even with the option -set x, it gives me the same file.err containing the same error as before

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark yes, it is, I already checked

Comment: you are doing it wrong. adding a `set -x` line should have each command printed and prefixed with a `+`.  please update your script so I can double check it.

Comment: I solved it by writing -np $NCPU at the end of the command

Comment: what is `/usr/lib64/openmpi/1.4-gcc/bin/mpiexec`? is this a legit Open MPI file or a (buggy) adhoc wrapper?